# Getting ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error when sending response

Tags: express

This is my request handler

```
 exports.index = function (req, res, next) {
    var question = getQuestion();
    console.log('index2 page');
    var response = res.json([{"message": `${question}`}]);
    console.log(`returning response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)
    return response;
```

When I send request, I see the following error

```
index2 page
GET /question 200 20.609 ms - 157
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    ...
```

What is causing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
 exports.index = function (req, res, next) {
    var question = getQuestion();
    console.log('index2 page');
    var response = [{"message": `${question}`}];
    console.log(`returning response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)
    return res.json(response);
}
```

Comment: worked. what is the difference between what I was doing vs what you recommended?

Comment: @ManuChadha You were calling `res.json` when initializing the variable, and then returning it again with `return response`, sending a response 2 times.